# Create a text file in FTP server (Commons-net)

Tags: java, ftp, text-files

I need help with Java Networking programming. I trying to create a new text file to FTP server. I found this code example in internet, but it's only creates a directory.
How to change it to text file format?

Here's the code:

```
public class FTPCreateDirDemo {
private static void showServerReply(FTPClient ftpClient) {
    String[] replies = ftpClient.getReplyStrings();
    if (replies != null && replies.length > 0) {
        for (String aReply : replies) {
            System.out.println("SERVER: " + aReply);
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String server = "www.yourserver.com";
    int port = 21;
    String user = "username";
    String pass = "password";
    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    try {
        ftpClient.connect(server, port);
        showServerReply(ftpClient);
        int replyCode = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)) {
            System.out.println("Operation failed. Server reply code: " + replyCode);
            return;
        }
        boolean success = ftpClient.login(user, pass);
        showServerReply(ftpClient);
        if (!success) {
            System.out.println("Could not login to the server");
            return;
        }
        // Creates a directory
        String dirToCreate = "/upload123";
        success = ftpClient.makeDirectory(dirToCreate);
        showServerReply(ftpClient);
        if (success) {
            System.out.println("Successfully created directory: " + dirToCreate);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to create directory. See server's reply.");
        }
        // logs out
        ftpClient.logout();
        ftpClient.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Oops! Something wrong happened");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a specialist of this library, but I think FTP is more about sending / receiving files from a remote server, than directly accessing to the remote file system. So to create a remote file, you should first create it locally (for instance, in a temporary directory), and then send it to the remote server. Check the documentation: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-1.4.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

And more especially this method:

```
public boolean storeFile(String remote, InputStream local)
              throws IOException
```

Given a local file "foo.txt", you can create an InputStream and send the file to remote end using that input stream:

```
    try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("foo.txt");) {
        ftpClient.storeFile("foo.txt", inputStream);
    }
```

[edit] Note that since the methods takes an InputStream as parameter, you can eventually use something else than a local file as the input: you could also directly read from String.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread but for anyone who is also looking for a way to write a Java String directly to a remote text file via FTP here's the solution I found using a regular InputStream from a String:

```
String inputString = "Filecontent for remote Server";
try (InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(inputString.getBytes())) {
     ftpClient.storeFile("foo.txt", targetStream);
}
```